# Function to turn list of ints into hexadecimal representation

Tags: python, hex

I have the function `hex2int` as follows:

```
import binascii

def hex2int(hexdata):
    return [ord(c) for c in binascii.unhexlify(hexdata)]
```

which turns a string like

```
'000000000000000000030c1a314a616d72614d331f0e0603010100000000000000010101010000010305060502000000021c4179b1dcedd2a76e41210e0906040403020202020100020825528dcdf2ffe0a86f3b22130c0a08060402000000000001010203020100000000000000000000000000000203030200000000020307142c5584a8bba37c4e28160c080603000000000000000001010101010101010101000000000000000d285c93c5dac7a06c4226160f0a0704030303030403030100000000000000000002030405040301000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007111c2732404d5a61675f5342322118100d0a080604020100'
```

into the following list:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 12, 26, 49, 74, 97, 109, 114, 97, 77, 51, 31, 14, 6, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 28, 65, 121, 177, 220, 237, 210, 167, 110, 65, 33, 14, 9, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 8, 37, 82, 141, 205, 242, 255, 224, 168, 111, 59, 34, 19, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 7, 20, 44, 85, 132, 168, 187, 163, 124, 78, 40, 22, 12, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 40, 92, 147, 197, 218, 199, 160, 108, 66, 38, 22, 15, 10, 7, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 17, 28, 39, 50, 64, 77, 90, 97, 103, 95, 83, 66, 50, 33, 24, 16, 13, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 0]
```

I am trying to write the inverse function `int2hex` that takes this list and returns the first string.

I currently have

```
def int2hex(intdata):
    return binascii.hexlify(''.join([hex(i) for i in intdata]))
```

but that doesn't return the correct result. Could you please explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `format()`:

```
''.join(format(my_int, '02x') for my_int in my_list)
```

which formats each integer value as a 2-digit lowercase hexadecimal value with a leading 0 if the value is lower than 16.

Answer (score 4):

Without comprehensions for Python 2.7+:

```
binascii.hexlify(bytearray(my_list))
```

On Python 2.6 it needs a 'readonly' buffer, unlike bytearray.:

```
binascii.hexlify(buffer(bytearray(my_list)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print ''.join("%02x"%my_int for my_int in my_list)
```

Comment: fixed ...  :P  I didnt realize he had 2 character reprs in first string till i ran it against my solution

Comment: The int list had values 0 - 255, and bytes are generally in that range anyway. :-)

Comment: yeah :P I just didnt look that close :P

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers here that address the problem you're having, but don't explain why you're having it.

When you run

```
 >>> binascii.unhexlify(hexdata)
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x0c\x1a1JamraM3\x1f\x0e\x06\x03x01\x01x00x00x00x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x03\x05\x06\x05\x02\x00\x00x00x02x1cAy\xb1\xdc\xed\xd2\xa7nA!\x0e\t\x06\x04\x04\x03\x02\x02\x02\x02\x01\x00x02x08%Rx8d\xcd\xf2\xff\xe0\xa8o;"\x13\x0c\n\x08\x06\x04\x02\x00\x00\x00x00x00x01x01x02\x03\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x00x02x03x03\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x03\x07\x14,U\x84\xa8\xbb\xa3|N(\x16x0cx08x06x03x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01x01x01x01\x00x00x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r(\\\x93\xc5\xda\xc7\xa0lB&\x16\x0f\n\x07x04x03\x03\x03x03x04\x03\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x03\x04\x05'\x04\x03x01x00x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x00x00\x00\x07\x11\x1c\'2@MZag_SB2!\x18\x10\r\n\x08\x06\x04\x02\x01\x00'
```

you're getting a string where each character's binary value is the number you want (hence `'\x00'`, which is why you're using `ord()`

However, you're running

```
 >> ''.join([hex(i) for i in intdata])
 '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'
```

Which is giving you an ascii representation. You need to use `chr()` to do it your way, or use one of the nice alternatives from one of the other answers.